# In Vim, how do I have the default behavior when opening a Python file be open all folds

Tags: vim, folding

I have this in my `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal foldmethod=indent
```

so that I can use `zr` `zR` `zm` `zM` to see different levels of my Python files. The only thing is when I open a Python script, it's folded by default and I have to use `zR` to open all the folds. I don't want to do the extra `zR` every time I open a file. How do I set the default behavior upon opening a file be to open all the folds? Is there something along the lines of "apply `zR` upon opening" or something else that does the same thing?

Comment: See `:help 'foldlevelstart'`.

Comment: I added `autocmd FileType python setlocal foldlevelstart=99` to my .vimrc and that didn't work. I don't know why. I also tried with foldlevelstart=0 and then -1. 
Instead I just added `autocmd BufWinEnter *.py normal! zR`, which worked.

Comment: Read that help section again. `0` is like… the opposite of what you want.

Comment: also tried 99 and -1. I edited above to say this

Comment: Do you have any modeline stuff in your .vimrc?  `This is done before reading any modeline, thus a setting in a modeline overrules this option.`

Comment: @m_mlvx, this is all I have in my .vimrc before the above. I don't have modeline but I have 'set' statements.
syntax on  
set number  
set relativenumber
set laststatus=2
set incsearch
set listchars=tab:>>,nbsp:~  
set expandtab
set tabstop=4 
set shiftwidth=4
map q <Nop>